# Generate file digest using data, file ownership & permission and others

Tags: bash, hashsum

I'd like to be able to detect when a file is considered different if the data are still the same but the ownership has changed (or the permission, access/creation time, etc...).

Is there a such tool ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the answer provided by [Detect changes in permissions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175384/detect-changes-in-permissions), you can determine the time of permission changes and the actual permissions by using the `stat` command.

So something like that should work:

```
stat -c "%a %Z" file | cat - file | sha1sum
```

Comment: I guess this method is particularly useful if one wants to consider a specific subset of metadata and to ignore the rest.

Answer (score 0):

```
tar -cf - --no-recursion the_file | sha256sum
```

Notes:

- `--no-recursion` in case `the_file` is of the type directory. I assumed you want to detect changes to the file itself, not to its subdirectories and such.
- `tar` does not store atime. This means the method cannot detect any change in atime of `the_file`. On the other hand the sole act of reading `the_file` by `tar` may update its atime (depending on mount options), so ignoring atime is most likely a good thing.
- If there's a problem with `tar`, you will still get some digest (the digest of empty input) and exit status 0 from `sha256sum`. See [*Get exit status of process that's piped to another*](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/14270/108618).
- `tar` stores the path. The method is sensitive not only to the actual name of the file, but primarily to the pathname *you provide*. E.g. specifying `./the_file` will give you a different digest than `the_file`. To reliably detect changes, pick a pathname and stick to it.
- You can use another `*sum` tool (e.g. `md5sum`). Pick one and stick to it.

Comment: thanks but changing the filename can't be used to compute a digest.

Comment: @A.G. Well, *I had to guess* if "others" in the title and "etc." in the body should include the filename. I guessed wrong.

Comment: Sorry for not precising but I was thinking it was obvious that the filename is never included in a digest since it refers to a different file.